# Desafio na Implementação da Barra de Pesquisa do Web Browser: Atualização Incorreta do Link

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

**Introdução**

Durante a implementação da funcionalidade de barra de pesquisa, deparei-me com um problema intrigante: o link exibido na barra permanece desatualizado, mesmo após a navegação para uma nova página.
**Imagens**

Imagem 1: link da imagem 1

Imagem 2: link da imagem 2

Imagem 3: link da imagem 3

**Descrição Detalhada do Projeto**

Meu projeto envolve a utilização do componente WebView2, bem como de um ToolStrip para exibir os botões e a barra de pesquisa. Também faço uso de um Tab Control e, é claro, do próprio WebView2.
Acredito que o erro esteja relacionado à integração entre a barra de pesquisa e o WebView, mas apesar de minhas extensas pesquisas, ainda não encontrei uma solução para o problema.

**Código**

A seguir está o código relevante do projeto:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MyHighBrowser
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_voltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.GoBack();
        }

        private void btn_atualizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.Refresh();
        }

        private void btn_avancar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webView.GoForward();
        }

        private void btn_ir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Txt_pesquisa.Text != "https://")
            {
                webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Txt_pesquisa.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Digite uma URL");
                Txt_pesquisa.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void Txt_pesquisa_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
                webView.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Txt_pesquisa.Text);
            }
        }

        private void Txt_pesquisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        private void webView_NavigationStarting(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            Txt_pesquisa.Text = webView.Source.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nunca duplique postagens. Acesse [sua pergunta original](/q/584291/70), restaure-a se necessário, e siga as orientações dadas lá, editando-a (tem uns links no comentário que podem ajudar muito na elaboração da pergunta, tire um tempinho pra estudar a [help] e respectivos links, pode fazer bastante diferença). Ao editar, ela é destacada para a comunidade reavaliar via voto. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, o espaço de comentários dessa aqui foi desativado, mas você pode usar na postagem original.